# Is it possible to add a link to download a file that can only be downloaded by sharing it on Facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, download, sharing

Is this scenario possible?

Customer goes to my website, wants to download a PDF technical document that interests them, they click the Download button and a Facebook share window appears to log them in to share it to Facebook.  Once they click Share and it is posted on their wall then the download begins?

Many thanks.

Ian

Comment: That would violate [Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/): “You must not incentivize users to use (or gate content behind the use of) Facebook social channels, or imply that an incentive is directly tied to the use of our channels.”

Answer (score 19):

### UPDATE

According to a Facebook new policy, this act is not allowed. Use it at your own risk. I hold no responsibilities for using this.

Yes, using the [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/), it provides a `response` (it doesn't anymore)
We will create an `if` statement to see if the response has a `post_id` if yes show the download link else do something else (alert the user, maybe?)

[**DEMO (API 2.0) (not working; revision required)**](http://jsfiddle.net/adamazad/7Bu5v/63/)

[**DEMO (API 2.7) working Rev#63**](http://jsfiddle.net/adamazad/7Bu5v/63/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    
    <div>
       <p>This file is locked, to unlock and download it, share it</p>
       <p class="hidden">Thanks for sharing, the file is unlocked and ready for download</p>
       <p class="hidden">In order to download this file, you need to share it</p>
    </div>

    <a class="fsl fsl-facebook" href="#" id="facebook-share">
       <span class="fa-facebook fa-icons fa-lg"></span>
       <span class="sc-label">Share on Facebook</span>
    </a>

    <a class="fsl content-download" href="#" id="download-file">
       <span class="fa-download fa-icons fa-lg"></span>
       <span class="sc-label">Download File</span>
    </a>
    
</div>
```

**JavaScript (jQuery)**

```
$('#ShareToDownload').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            FB.ui({
                  display: 'popup',
                  method:  'share',
                  href:    location.href,
                  },
                  /** our callback **/
                  function(response) {
                          if (response && response.post_id) {
                          /** the user shared the content on their Facebook, go ahead and continue to download **/
                          $('#ShareToDownload').fadeOut(function(){ $('#downloadSection').fadeIn() });    
                          } else {
                          /** the cancelled the share process, do something, for example **/
                          alert('Please share this page to download this file'):
                  }
            });     
});
```

### UPDATE

With the release of **API version 2.0** the **Feed dialog was deprecated** and replaced with the new modern [**Share Dialog**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) so the above code uses the new **Share Dialog**

Comment: Thank you so much Adam!  This is superb!

Comment: Sorry to disturb. Is this script usable for API2.5? If so could you please provide a full code here. Your demo was banned.

Comment: @Wilf, I believe these method are still working in API2.5. Nonetheless, I will sort out the issue with the jsFiddle and check if it's working. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Adam, your very soon future script would save the world. Please create the solution for this...

Comment: @Wilf, I just got a reply from jsFiddle, they unblocked the fiddle. And, the fiddle got updated. Please, check if the fiddle, note that you need to modify the iframe source to allow the popup to work. Here's how to do so http://stackoverflow.com/a/32721395/2151050

Comment: @AdamAzad, You are a genius! Thank you a millionnnnnnnnnnnnnz!

Comment: @AdamAzad, your script works great until I finished sharing the content. The download button doesn't show up. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, works perfect! I Didn't know how to get the download link from a JSON file, so I did it slightly different, maybe not that safe.

Add this to the section where the response is checked

```
$.post('optimus.php', { 'fieldname' : 'download', 'value' : 'yes'});
```

Made a new page where the session is set (optimus.php)

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION[$_POST['fieldname']] = $_POST['value'];
?>
```

Download.php contains the following code

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['download'] ==  "yes"){
session_destroy();
$file = 'file.zip';

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
} else {
    echo "You didn't share, or you already downloaded the file";
}
?>
```

So, when the user shared something, the $_SESSION['download'] is set to yes. Download.php checks if it's yes and when it is the download is automatically started. Also, the session is destroyed so they can only download once.