# Check if user shared on Facebook

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-like

I'm looking for a way to check if people shared on Facebook. After they have shared, they will be redirected to another page.

So far, I've found the code below. It will present the user with a like page. When they click it, they can share something too. The problem is that edge.create will get a postive response BEFORE something is shared. So it only checks for the like, not for the share..

Is there a way to check if the user has shared?

Thank you!

```
    <html>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'ID', // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
   function(response) {
        window.open ('page.html,'_self',false)    
   }
); 
  };

  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
  </script>

  <fb:like href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJTXDCh2YiA" 
     send="true" width="450" show_faces="false"
     >
</fb:like>
</html>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19131177/2151050