# Facebook share link, remote iframe click event capture

Tags: facebook, cross-domain, facebook-iframe, facebook-sharer

I am working from last 24 hours to accomplish this, i can't capture the fb share link widget iframe click event, i need to perform an operation over it. If its not possible due to cross domain, even then i need some logic to get a click event triggered on the parent div of this iframe, parent div is in my DOM element.

Comment: Because i need to perform it on my project.

Comment: Need to capture the CLICK event on the facebook SHARE LINK widget, so that i can perform some task @HarikrishnanT

Comment: I was actually asking did you already try anything or you just posted like that? If you already did try something but didn't work, please post the code.

Comment: Did tried, binding iframe click, binding iframe parent div click, binding iframe child element click, tried to get IF click was performed with in the PARENT div dimensions. Everything.

Comment: You can use the JS SDK http://stackoverflow.com/a/19131177/2151050

Comment: This is FEED sharing, there is a widget for sharing the LINK, that's different. @AdamAzad

Comment: Aha.. You're stuck :)! because the only way to track user shares and likes is to use the js-sdk

Comment: I suppose I already posted a link

Comment: i have made my own :D and its the similar like the original one :p

Comment: But i wanna know, why browsers don't allow to override the events for iframes when fetching from cross domain:(