# Is there a way to store the likes,share of facebook,google in database?

Tags: facebook, twitter, google-plus

I am developing a site..in which we have pictures,video which users can share/like/tweet 
them.

**facebook , google and twitter**

Can i save the clicks by getting response that post is shared successfully?

eg: someone liked/shared the video than i want to get a response from facebook that post is shared successfully.

also if some liked and then disliked it ..to save only unique likes

Is there any way to accomplish this?

I found something for fb share [Is it possible to add a link to download a file that can only be downloaded by sharing it on Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130267/is-it-possible-to-add-a-link-to-download-a-file-that-can-only-be-downloaded-by-s/19131177#19131177)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the best by-the-book solution but you could attach an `onclick` event handler to each of the buttons (or iframe container).

Also, for the Facebook API you can use [edge.create](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/). I am not too familiar with the other APIs.