# How to implement FB share necessary to download a file

Tags: javascript, facebook, wordpress, facebook-social-plugins

I have a pdf file regarding some exam preparation. I would like the visitors to share the page /article in order to download the file. When they click the download link , i want to show the visitors a pop up message " Share in FB to download File "  with Fb share box. Any idea how i could implement this?

Comment: According to Facebook Platform Policy https://developers.facebook.com/policy 4.5 it is not allowed to incentivize shares: "Only incentivize a person to log into your app, like your app’s Page, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions".

And in their examples they specifically show that it is not allowed to do it with shares.

Comment: You can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19131177/2151050