# FB.ui not returing post id in response

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am following this thread [Is it possible to add a link to download a file that can only be downloaded by sharing it on Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130267/is-it-possible-to-add-a-link-to-download-a-file-that-can-only-be-downloaded-by-s/19131177#19131177) to detect if user share my given link or not, If user share then allow him to access the next level.

This is how i am doing:

```
FB.ui({
                display: 'popup',
                method:  'share',
                href: 'url-here',
            } , function(response){
                console.log(response.e2e)
                if (response && response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: ajaxurl, 
                        type: 'post', 
                        data: {action: 'unlock_om_gmap'}, 
                        success: function(res) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

But everytime its returning `Object { e2e="{"submit_0":1406412308276}"}` not any post id. Is there anyone familiar with this issue? How do i check if user shared my link or not?

Comment: It is not allowed to incentivizing sharing on Facebook.

Comment: Has the user both logged into Facebook and also granted your app the "publish_actions" permission? According to the docs, you'll only get the object ID in the response if both of those are true: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#response

Comment: @dshap i haven't included any permission yet, Just using the simple share. Should i include the permissions too?

Comment: @jogesh_pi Yea. This never used to be the case with the legacy share dialog, but with the new one, it seems you cannot determine if the user actually made a post (vs. just clicking "cancel") unless the user has authorized your app and granted you the permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, as per the [Facebook docs on this topic](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#response), you'll need to check for an `object_id` property in the response data to determine if an Open Graph story was shared, but this is only available if the user is logged into your app using Facebook and has granted `publish_actions`