# facebook share before download

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wish to set up a facebook share gate to access my files in my website. when the user shares my website on their facebook acct, they can download the file. otherwise, no. This question is pretty similar to the post below. I tried the demo provided by adam with the downloaded file link inserted to the code. But it failed. It just show the file without popping out the usual facebook share dialogue in my website. However, if i tried the demo there, it did pop out the share dialogue together with the file even before i share. Am I missing something in the code? as i just copy the code in the demo to my website. Thank you.

[Is it possible to add a link to download a file that can only be downloaded by sharing it on Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130267/is-it-possible-to-add-a-link-to-download-a-file-that-can-only-be-downloaded-by-s/19131177#19131177)

`

```
<div>
   <p>This file is locked, to unlock and download it, share it</p>
   <p class="hidden">Thanks for sharing, the file is unlocked and ready for download</p>
   <p class="hidden">In order to download this file, you need to share it</p>
</div>
<a class="fsl fsl-facebook" href="#" id="facebook-share">
   <span class="fa-facebook fa-icons fa-lg"></span>
   <span class="sc-label">Share on Facebook</span>
</a>

<a class="fsl content-download" href="http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140510200316/spiritanimals/images/0/05/Tiger.jpg" id="download-file">
   <span class="fa-download fa-icons fa-lg"></span>
   <span class="sc-label">Download File</span>
</a>
```

`
[adam's demo code](http://jsfiddle.net/adamazad/7Bu5v/)

Comment: That is not allowed by Facebook Platform Policy.