# how to know if facebook share is done or not?

Tags: jquery, facebook

When user clicks share button on my page then a prompt box is open to share it... i want to get back the response whether share is done or not.

I am using facebook og

Code:

```
<script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }

        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="fb-share-button" data-type="button"></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Read this answer, it's the same way, but for a different purpose http://stackoverflow.com/a/19131177/2151050

Comment: @AdamAzad thanks but i don't want to use appid..if i remove that part its not working

Comment: Why don't you want to use an appid?

Comment: Thanks for this..but it always giving "no" as response whether it is shared or not

Comment: @AdamAzad and your demo is also not working ...reponse is always no

Comment: It works :) _"reponse is always no"_ I don't know how did you come up with that conclusion but probably you messed with the fiddle, anyways you need an app ID

Comment: no..i did nothing with fiddle