# How to give permission to user for download files from website after sharing it on Facebook?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want that when user try to download any pdf/doc/zip file from my website then first of all user will share something about my website on his/her Facebook wall and after successfully share download link will enable.

I got one solution for this question on Stack Overflow but this is not 100% correct. Because this solution is able to share on Facebook but after share the download link is not appear. The Below link is solution for Stack Overflow answer.

[Is it possible to add a link to download a file that can only be downloaded by sharing it on Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130267/is-it-possible-to-add-a-link-to-download-a-file-that-can-only-be-downloaded-by-s)

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. What did you try?

Comment: @Chilion i think you can understand my question. Because you are too genius thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: share or like gating is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook changed the behavior of it's share dialog recently. Before that, the dialog sent a response which included the post id when something was successfully shared, and did not when it wasn't without the need of having the user authenticated.

However, currently **Facebooks share dialog does not send the post ID along with the response when the user is not connected to your application and did not grant the `publish_actions` permission for your app.**

[Regarding the `post_id` the docs state:](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog)

> Only available if the user is logged into your app using Facebook and has granted publish_actions. If present, this is the ID of the published Open Graph story.

If you want to do it anyways you have to go through the whole mess of the [authentication flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.2), which probably isn't worth it.

**Additionally requesting the `publish_actions` permission will require your app to be [reviewed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review#submitlogin). Since gating of any kind is not permitted by facebook, the `publish_actions` permission will not get approved. Currently there is no way to implement this feature.**

[See Facebooks Developer Platform Policy (4.5)](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/)

(thanks to [luschn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/757508/luschn) for the hint)

---

That all breaks down to a few principles:

- Deliver good content and do not make it dependent on user interaction
- Do not force the user to socially interact with your application. If they want to they'll do so on their own behalves
- At least the Javascript SDK is a pain to implement properly. Avoid it whenever possible. Use Social Features as an additional bonus and not a necessity.
- Facebook changes it's API every now and then. The API is incredibly unreliable which forces you to make changes to your code every few months if it heavily relies on Social Features.

Comment: The answer in your linked question is perfectly valid if the user is authenticated and granted the `publish_actions` permission. You just need to authenticate the user beforehand. A full auth implementation example is linked in my answer (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.2)

Comment: share or like gating is not allowed. you will never get publish_actions approved for this. you should add that very impoortant information to your answer.

Comment: @luschn thanks! I did not know that `publish_actions` will require your app to go through the app review process. I'll add that

Comment: btw, you can also add a link to the platform policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ - 4.5 is the relevant part (well, everything in that document is relevant to read BEFORE creating any app).

Comment: @luschn thanks for critically improving my answer :)

Comment: you´re welcome. always happy to help when developers are trying to gate stuff :) - users should share or like something because they really want to, not because they are forced to.