# JavaScript on click

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get this phone number validation of the ground, but I am having issues with the `onclick` method, why is this not working?

```js
function validatePhone(){
    var phone  = document.getElementById("phone1").value;
    if(phone.length === 0) {
        alert("phone number is required.");
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <p>Please enter your phone number below:</p>
    <input id="phone1" placeholder="(000)000-0000" />
    <input type="submit" value="send message" onclick="validatePhone()" />
</form>
```

Comment: From the error console: *Ignored call to 'alert()'. The document is sandboxed, and the 'allow-modals' keyword is not set.* — It is working, you just can't run alerts from a stackoverflow snippet.

Comment: it works all fine for me. I don't get what your problem is.

Comment: Are you using iframes? If so, take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32119446/ignored-call-to-alert-the-document-is-sandboxed-and-the-allow-modals-key

Comment: But it will allow it to post if the user types just one number

Comment: Or if the user types letters for that matter.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue... because even if I console.log instead of alert, I am still getting the error.... if I move the onclick function to the input with the phone1 id it works, but it doesn't work if the onclick is on the submit input.... maybe I am doing something wrong...

Comment: _"even if I console.log instead of alert, I am still getting the error"_ You never say what the error ***is*** ... you say "I am having issues" and "why is this not working".  Part of why this doesn't work is because it's a _snippet_. See https://jsfiddle.net/6jmhaarf/ ... if you put the javascript in the "JavaScript" panel of the fiddle it doesn't work, but put it in script tags and it works fine. As a `submit` not a `button`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change type of input to `button` because if type is submit `validatePhone()` will be never reached :

```js
function validatePhone()
{
    var phone  = document.getElementById("phone1").value;

    if(phone.length === 0) {
        document.getElementById("result").textContent ="phone number is required.";
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <p>Please enter your phone number below:</p>
    <input id="phone1" placeholder="(000)000-0000" />
    <input type="button" value="send message" onclick="validatePhone()" />
</form>
<span id='result'></span>
```

Or you can use `onsubmit` :

```js
function validatePhone(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    var phone  = document.getElementById("phone1").value;

    if(phone.length === 0) {
        document.getElementById("result").textContent ="phone number is required.";

        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="validatePhone()"
    <p>Please enter your phone number below:</p>
    <input id="phone1" placeholder="(000)000-0000" />
    <input type="submit" value="send message" />
</form>
<span id='result'></span>
```

Comment: @Zakaria - I didn't suggest the _onsubmit_ event, I said it should work fine with `<input type="submit">` and doesn't need to be `<input type="button">`. See my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6jmhaarf/  
(However, I usually ***attach*** onsubmit handlers myself; no inline javascript)

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Some people still use keyboard. Why validation should be onclick?

Comment: Okay @StephenP thanks for your explanation, however i try to prevent submit just inside condition using `return false` but it not work (i'm not sure why), but i think my answer don't deserve downvote :).

Comment: @MaksymKozlenko you suggestion (required) is important, but may he want to check using another condition not just empty condition.

Comment: @Zakaria I didn't downvote, I only commented. Take care with your assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add validation logic to `onsubmit` event on form element instead. Some people, like me, may use Enter button to submit form instead of using mouse.

Also you may add HTML5 `required` attribite and change type to **phone**, so mobile users will get numeric keypad

```
<input id="phone1" type="phone" required placeholder="(000)000-0000" />
```