# Ignored call to 'print()'. The document is sandboxed, and the 'allow-modals' keyword is not set. How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe, google-sites

I don't know much about web development and stuff. I am having trouble with my Google Site.
I want to embed a crossword, made with help of [Crossword Labs](https://crosswordlabs.com/). The embed code that this Crossword Labs gave me for a certain crossword looks like this [the below one is for a sample puzzle] :

```
<div style="margin:auto; display:flex; flex-direction:column; height:500px; max-width:500px">
<iframe border="0" src="https://crosswordlabs.com/embed/sample-crossword-64" style="flex:1; width:100%; padding:5px 0px 0 5px; border:3px solid black; "></iframe>
<a target="_blank" style="align-self:center; font-size:12px; color:black; padding-top:10px; text-decoration:none;text-align:center" href="https://crosswordlabs.com">Crossword Puzzle Maker</a>
```

The issue with this is: The print icon and 'Clear Puzzle' option in the Code is not working when I embed it in my Google Site.
[See this snippet to know what I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8JHc.png)

The error I am able to see when I open "Inspect Element" is

> Ignored call to 'print()'. The document is sandboxed, and the 'allow-modals' keyword is not set.

Please help me with this issue. And let me know if there is any lack of context. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I tried other solutions which were in similar lines. But none of them worked. So, a solution for this specific issue would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignored call to 'alert()'. The document is sandboxed, and the 'allow-modals' keyword is not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32119446/ignored-call-to-alert-the-document-is-sandboxed-and-the-allow-modals-key)