# PowerBI report embed error on print "The document is sandboxed, and the 'allow-modals' keyword is not set."

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I am embeding PowerBI reports in my website. Using powerbi-client it is fine. But from recent times after adding [new policy](https://chromestatus.com/feature/4747009953103872), I cannot do print of that report.
I receive error:

> Ignored call to 'print()'. The document is sandboxed, and the 'allow-modals' keyword is not set.

I checked topics like this [Ignored call to 'alert()'. The document is sandboxed, and the 'allow-modals' keyword is not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32119446/ignored-call-to-alert-the-document-is-sandboxed-and-the-allow-modals-key) and try to do this:

```
const report = powerbi.bootstrap(embedContainer, settings);
report.iframe.sandbox.add('allow-modals');
```

which is adding `allow-modals` value to sandbox attribute in generated by library `iframe`. But still issue is reproducible on `print`.

---

This code I call onclick of my print button

```
private onPrintPowerBiReport(): void {
    const report = powerbi.get(embedContainer);
    report.print();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a **Content-Security-Policy** feature blocking you. You need to add `allow-modals` to the headers.

[image: headers example]

Comment: yes, you are right... don't know why I thought it should be in iframe.

Comment: one more question - probably it's result of this update - in safari I got error: "The sandbox is too restrictive and preventing correct functioning." - did you met that error?

Comment: I do not have that error but I think it has something to do with javascript being blocked or limited in Safari. I see when google crawls powerbi reports they are capturing "The sandbox is too restrictive and preventing correct functioning." exactly like what you ran into. https://www.google.com/search?q=PowerBI+%22The+sandbox+is+too+restrictive+and+preventing+correct+functioning%22